# remove decimal from type double number but keep type double

Tags: dart

```
double num  = 333.5;
```

I need to the keep the type `double` but remove the decimal part of a number. Currently I'm

```
String numString = num.toStringAsFixed(0) (334)
```

which gets rid of the decimal. But I need to pass the number as a double.  So I then

```
double.parse(numString) (334.0)
```

but this introduces the decimal again. Strange thing is... In dartpad the `.0` (`334`)zero doesn't show which is desired. But in my environment the zero does show (334.0) .

Comment: It is unclear what are you trying to achieve. If the goal is to show the number without decimal on UI, then convert it .toStringAsFixed(0) directly on UI, and do all the operations with it before that. if you want something different, provide a code snippet

Comment: `double`s will always show a decimal when converted to a `String`.  If that's not what you want, then you'll need to use `.toStringAsFixed(0)` when you print/display it instead of relying on the default `.toString()` implementation.  You won't see `.0` printed in DartPad because Dart for the Web is transpiled to JavaScript, and JavaScript does not have a separate integer type (all numbers are represented as IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point numbers).  Dart for the Web therefore uses heuristics to identify numbers that are *probably* `int`s, and in cases like this it guessed incorrectly.

Comment: the package (fl_chart) I'm using requires a double being passed for the tooltip when the the user touches the graph. I don't want to show the decimal in the tooltip. Suppose I have to modify package.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

It's worked for me

`num.round().toDouble(); ===>> (334)`

Comment: still getting '334.0'

Comment: in that case, you will take it as an integer because double is represent (0.0).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is also [`num.roundToDouble`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-core/num/roundToDouble.html) which doe the same thing in one step.